# Cubic Bézier: What to do when leading coefficient is zero?

Tags: c++, math, bezier

I use a fairly standard method to retrieve the monic polynomial coefficients from a cubic Bézier curve's control points:

```
std::array<double, 3> getBezierCubicCoefficients( const std::array<double, 4>& bezier )
{
    const auto d = 1.0 / ( bezier[3] - 3*bezier[2] + 3*bezier[1] - bezier[0] );
    return { ( 3*bezier[2] - 6*bezier[1] + 3*bezier[0] ) * d,
             ( 3*bezier[1] - 3*bezier[0] ) * d,
             bezier[0] * d };
}
```

This works fine 99% of the time, but as you have probably guessed, fails under certain coordinates which cause `d`'s divisor to evaluate to zero - causing `d` to evaluate to `Inf`.

My question is: what to do under this circumstance?

Have I actually got a quadratic curve in disguise, and should I perform degree reduction instead?  Should I just fudge the numbers so `d` is very large, but won't cause `Inf`s? (I really hope that isn't the answer).

Comment: Why do you return only three coefficients for a cubic curve? Shouldn't that be four?

Comment: @NicoSchertler It returns the coefficients in monic polynomial form, so the first coefficient is 1 - and therefore implicit.

Comment: To be clear, you want coefficients `k`, such that the curve `c(t) = t^3 + k1 t^2 + k2 t + k3`?

Comment: If so, then yes. If the denominator of `d` becomes zero, you have a degree-2 curve (at most). Anyway, I doubt that scaling the polynomial is a good idea anyway because this will also scale the curve.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I'm normalising the polynomial as it will be used to find the roots inside an implementation of Cadano's method, it won't be used for drawing. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already know, the monomic coefficients `c` can be calculated from the Bezier coefficients by multiplying with the following matrix:

```
                              / 1  -3   3  -1 \
                              |     3  -6   3 |
(c0 c1 c2 c3) = (b0 b1 b2 b3) |         3  -3 |
                              \ 0           1 /
```

If the resulting `c3 = -b0 + 3b1 - 3b2 + b3` is zero, then you'll get a quadratic polynomial (at most). In degenerate cases, other coefficients can yield `0`, too. In the edge case, you end up with a constant.